# Sort 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
[105][2500]
[110][1800]
[105][800]
[105][1300]
[110][1200]
...
```

And I need this:

```
[105][800]
[105][1300]
[105][2500]
[110][1200]
[110][1800]
...
```

NEW EDIT: That's my code now:
row is nuber of rows, array is that 2D int array[row][2]

```
 ...
 for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);

 qsort(array, row, 2*sizeof(int), compare);

 printf("\n sorted: \n");
 for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
 ...
```

compare function:

```
int compare(void const *p_lhs, void const *p_rhs) {
  int const *lhs = (int const *) p_lhs;
  int const *rhs = (int const *) p_rhs;

//  printf("%d %d  - %d %d", lhs[0], rhs[0], lhs[1], rhs[1]);
  if(lhs[0] < rhs[0]) return -1;
  if(lhs[0] > rhs[0]) return  1;
  if(lhs[1] < rhs[1]) return -1;
  if(lhs[1] > rhs[1]) return  1;

  return 0;
}
```

output with pritf in compare function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP7wN.png
output is:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDl1k.png

Comment: use `qsort` <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 3):

Happily, there's `qsort` for that in the standard library. Really all you have to do is provide a comparison function for elements of the outer array. For example:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// lexicographical comparison.
// Returns -1 for lhs < rhs, 1 for lhs > rhs, 0 for lhs == rhs.
int compare_line(void const *p_lhs, void const *p_rhs) {
  // These point to the elements of the outer arrays (that is,
  // they point to the inner arrays)
  double const *lhs = (double const *) p_lhs;
  double const *rhs = (double const *) p_rhs;

  if(lhs[0] < rhs[0]) return -1;
  if(lhs[0] > rhs[0]) return  1;
  if(lhs[1] < rhs[1]) return -1;
  if(lhs[1] > rhs[1]) return  1;

  return 0;
}

#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof*(arr))

int main(void) {
  double data[][2] = {
    { 105,  800 },
    { 105, 1300 },
    { 105, 2500 },
    { 110, 1200 },
    { 110, 1800 }
  };

  // Sorting here.
  qsort(data, ARRAY_SIZE(data), sizeof(data[0]), compare_line);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(data); ++i) {
    printf("%lf %lf\n", data[i][0], data[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say what's happening without a test case. My suspicion is that you're passing the array to a function (making it a pointer) and try to use my `ARRAY_SIZE` macro on it. The macro can only work on arrays because `sizeof(arr)` will not give the size of the array once it's decayed to a pointer; it will give the size of the pointer.

Comment: Use `qsort(array, row, 2*sizeof(int), compare);`

Comment: The error is not in the code you posted. Build a minimal, compileable example that still exhibits the error, then I can help. It was odd, by the way, that you didn't get garbage in your output when you sorted four times as much memory as was in the array; are you sure this bit of code is being executed and not some other version of it?

Comment: ' printf("%d %d  - %d %d", lhs[0], rhs[0], lhs[1], rhs[1]);' in compare function, on line above ifs, i get memory adresses.