# Convert const void pointer to int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

compiler shows me that:

```
In function ‘int compare(const void*, const void*)’:
invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive] 
invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
```

That's my function:

```
int compare(void const *a, void const *b) {
  int *a2 = (int*)a;
  int *b2 = (int*)b;

  int *uziv1=*((const int**)a2);
  int *uziv2=*((const int**)b2);

  if(abs(uziv1[0]) < abs(uziv2[0])) return -1;
  if(abs(uziv1[0]) > abs(uziv2[0])) return  1;
  if(abs(uziv1[1]) < abs(uziv2[1])) return -1;
  if(abs(uziv1[1]) > abs(uziv2[1])) return  1;

  return 0;
}
```

I need to convert the two pointers from void to int to read from the array they point to and compare the values. The function needs to have the given signature such that it can be used for `qsort`.

Comment: Show the relevant part of the code calling qsort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27166757/971127

Comment: ` qsort(array, count, sizeof(int**), compare);`

Answer (score 1):

Converting from a `const` pointer to a normal pointer is not allowed, because this would break the guarantee given by `const` (nobody should be able to write to it).

However, as you only want to read from these pointers, it is possible (and recommended) to simply declare them as `const`. Then you even do not need any cast at all:

```
const int *uziv1 = a;
const int *uziv2 = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finaly fix it with:

```
...
  int const *uziv1=*(( int const **)a);
  int const *uziv2=*(( int const **)b);
...
```

Comment: Editing questions in the way you propose is wrong. Question is question and answer is answer and both should be separated here. This answer looks like fine for me so no reason to complain or downvote. IF that solved his problem, it should end as accepted answer too.